# Validate PDF form before submitting document

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have created a pdf form for work and am unable to solve my problem.

I have a form that has required fields and radio fields.  I need to do 1 or 2 things.  I would like for the form to validate all required form fields before the customer can sign the document.  Which would be my first choice, but if unable to do that if I can get the form to validate before they select submit.

So basically it need the pdf form to:

1. validate all required form fields,
2. sign the document
3. Lock the document
4. submit the document.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Adobe Acrobat or Reader to fill and sign the form, you can easily do this with a bit of JavaScript in the signature field. Set the required fields to "required" in the field properties. Acrobat will automatically force the user to fill them before submitting the document.

Comment: I have set all the fields to required, however I still am unable to validate all fields are filled before they sign, especially the radio fields.  I have looked for a Java script on this but have not found anything yet.

Comment: Can you post the form?

Comment: Screen Shot 2017-03-25 at 11.52.33 AM

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my form that I need help with.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the form I need help with.

Comment: Ok - So you *actually* want is for the form to get validated before they can sign and then only be able to submit once it *is* signed. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I would like the form to validate before they sign, however I can't figure out how to do that with the required radio buttons.

Comment: Ok - So if that's the case, you'll need to add a hidden calculated field that will do the validation and then toggle the enabled property of the signature field and the submit button based on the result. Radio button values are strings and are either "Off" or the string that you set for the export value, by default that's "Yes".

Comment: @joelgeraci- Would you happen to know a script that includes the radio button validate.  I have found several online; however nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Without having access to your form, I can't tell you exactly what the code would be but if no radio button in the group is set to be on by default, then what you're looking for is a blank string. The blank string as a value of a radio button means that the user has not interacted with any of the buttons in the group. Otherwise, the value of the field will be the value of the selected button in the group. Be sure that grouped buttons use the same field name or you'll never get the validation to work properly.